# How to connect to a router's interface that is an other internal network than my router? Remote management?

Tags: router, lan, home-networking, ip-address

I want to ask a simple question: Is there a way to know a router's LAN address thats not directly connected to my router, but the router before my router? All 3 of them are TP-Link TL-WR1043ND routers. I know i could like just look it up by connecting a computer to it, but I still dont know if I can actually access the router cross 2 other routers. I drawed the diagram:

[image: Network diagram]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to router 1 in your diagram? Just type into your browser that ip address 192.168.1.1 . It will ask for admin name and password but if you know those it's no problem.

CCNA

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I'm trying to connect to Router 3. I think it's probably impossible without Remote management or disabling DHCP and connecting the cable that's connected to Router 3's WAN port to it's LAN port.